# Why is the $1-\alpha$ Bayesian credible interval for $\lambda \sim \chi^2_{v}$ have endpoints $\chi^2_{v, 1-\alpha/2}$ and $\chi^2_{v,\alpha/2}$?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, credible-interval

Suppose that a posterior distribution $\lambda$ has distribution $\lambda \sim \chi^2_{v}$.

Then, it is often written that a $1-\alpha$ Bayesian credible interval for $\lambda \sim \chi^2_{v}$ will have have lower and upper endpoints of $\chi^2_{v, 1-\alpha/2}$ and $\chi^2_{v,\alpha/2}$, respectively. I am wondering why the lower endpoint starts at $1-\alpha/2$ instead of $\alpha/2$? If $\alpha = 0.05$, then it seems weird for the lower point to start at $\chi^2_{v, 1-0.05/2} = \chi^2_{v, 0.975}$, which is the UPPER endpoint of a frequentist interval. Thanks.

[image: From Casella-Berger]

Comment: Could you direct us to any place where this is "written"?

Comment: There is a lot of missing information. What is the prior for lambda?  What is the data and the likelihood to give lambda a chi square posterior distribution? now regardless of this any posterior interval that contains (1-alpha )% of the posterior distribution is a (1-alpha)% credible region.  The same thing is true for frequentist confidence intervals with respect to coverage.  For symmetric distributions like the normal or the t distribution confidence intervals for the population mean are often centered around the sample mean.  Also there is a concept of shortest confidence interval.

Comment: Such a requirement like that makes the interval unique and I imagine it could be applied to credible regions as well.

Comment: But in your case you must have things mixed up because as you say if alpha is 0.05  we have X^2 (v , 0,975) is greater than X^2 (v, 0.025).  So it can't be a lower endpoint.  It just has to be a mistake or you misread it.

Comment: I have uploaded the example from Casella-Berger where I am referencing. On the above equation 9.2.20, the left point is through $1-\alpha/2$. This doesn't make sense for me. Thanks for any input, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I will look at it Casella-Berger is a reputable source.

Comment: You can see some of my questions are answered.  Lambda is the parameter from a Poisson distribution. You have a gamma prior (which is called a conjugate prior because the posterior for lambda also comes from the gamma family.  Not that Casella and Berger mention that the credible region is not unique.  The sample comes from n iid Poisson(lambda) variables which determines the likelihood.function allowing the derivation of the posterior distribution.  Now from the posterior distribution they claim to make the credible region unique by eliminating probability alpha /2 in each tail.

Comment: Also the specific form of the posterior gamma distribution happens to be a chi square with 14 degrees of freedom. The end points of the credible region can be determined from standard chi square tables. In the example they actually take alpha =0.10 and therefore alpha/2 is 0.05.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thanks, do you know why the lower endpoint is $\chi^2_{2(\sum x+ a), 1-\alpha/2}$ instead of $\chi^2_{2(\sum x+ a), \alpha/2}$?

Comment: Yes I am getting to that right now. My table shows that it is a matter of correctly interpreting the notation.  I get 6.571 for the lower end point and 23.685 for the upper end point just as they do!

Comment: The simple explanation is that the point in the table corresponds to the area to the right of that point is 0,95 for the lower end point and to the right of the upper end point is 0.05. So the notation is in agreement with the table.

Comment: @user1398057 If you like my answer and think it is complete I will write it up tomorrow as a formal answer and you can accept it.

Comment: I have summarized the discussion in my answer. I decided for the moment not to delete the above comments to avoid rehashing everything and to therefore be somewhat concise in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has **added the excerpt from the Casella-Berger book**.  It shows that the authors agree with the points I made about credible regions and confidence intervals.  **It clears up all my issues and answers all the questions I wrote in the comments.** The answer boils down to the fact that the resulting posterior distribution is chi-square with 14 degrees of freedom.  **Casella and Berger made the endpoints of the credible region unique by requiring equal probability alpha/2** ( 0.05 in the example) to be below the lower endpoint and above the upper endpoint. In a standard statistic textbook, I found that the endpoints given by Casella and Berger in the example agree exactly with the table.

Here is the key point that clears up the confusion. The simple explanation is that **the points in the table correspond to the area to the right of that point. Hence 0.95 in the example for the lower endpoint and 0.05 for the upper endpoint. So Casella and Berger's notation is consistent with the chi-square table.**

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm just a little confused still why 0.95 corresponds to the lower endpoint and 0.05 the upper endpoint. Shouldn't it be the opposite way around? Since on the chi-square table, 0.95 is to the far right, why shouldnt we have something like $\chi^2_{2(\sum x+ a), \alpha/2} \lambda \leq \chi^2_{2(\sum x+ a), 1-\alpha/2}$ instead? It seems that in Casella-Berger, the credible interval is the set of $\lambda$ which correspond to the far right and far left area of the tail, instead of the middle?

Comment: @user1398057 I will try to be a little clearer.  They take out the first 5% of the chi square distribution and that represents the lower endpoint of the credible region.  So now 95% of the distribution is to the right of the lower endpoint. Remember that we want the middle 90% of the distribution to describe the credible region.  So we still have to remove 5% in the right tail.  The unique point where that is achieved is the upper endpoint.  Now there is 5% of the distribution to the right of the upper endpoint.  Just like there is 95% of the distribution to the right of the lower endpoint.

Comment: Don't let the notation confuse you.  The motivation for the notation is that the probability to the right of the point determine what p to use as the subscript for that chi square point.  If you look at the chi square distribution table you will see that the endpoints are correct and the column numbers decrease from 1 to 0 going from left to right.

Comment: Thanks so much! I see where I got it wrong now, I kept thinking the chi square table started the area from the left instead of the right, like you said. Thanks again, very awesome answer!!

Comment: You are very welcome user1398057. I knew the light bulb would go off sooner or later.  I was hard pressed to think of what else I could say if you didn't get it.  This was fun working out the mystery.  I was puzzled by it at first also.